# Is there a way for a property to set its backing value?

Tags: c#, properties

I have a property, and I want it to set another property whenever it's being set. For example:

```
    private double Bpm
    {
        set
        {
            <myself> = value;
            _bps = <myself> / 60;
        }
        get
        {
            return <myself>;
        }
    }
```

What I actually did is the following, because I couldn't find another way:

```
    private double _bpm;
    private double _bps;

    private double Bpm
    {
        set
        {
            _bpm = value;
            _bps = _bpm / 60;
        }
        get
        {
            return _bpm;
        }
    }
```

I find it not elegant, having two private members `Bpm` and `_bpm`. I can also have a `SetBpm` method, but I want to know if this is achievable with properties.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A property is *just* a pair of methods, really - and if you use an automatically-implemented property, the compiler implements them for you and creates a field. You want one field - because you've only got one real value, and two views on it - so you can either get the compiler to create that field for you automatically by using an automatically-implemented property, or you can declare it yourself. I'd use an automatically-implemented property, personally. Then you calculate the *other* property based on the original. You can either make that a read-only property, or make it read-write.

For example, as a read-only version:

```
public double BeatsPerSecond { get; set; }
public double BeatsPerMinute { get { return BeatsPerSecond * 60; } }
```

Or in C# 6:

```
public double BeatsPerSecond { get; set; }
public double BeatsPerMinute => BeatsPerSecond * 60;
```

For a read-write version:

```
public double BeatsPerSecond { get; set; }
public double BeatsPerMinute
{
    get { return BeatsPerSecond * 60; }
    set { BeatsPerSecond = value / 60; }
}
```

You could decide to make `BeatsPerMinute` the "stored" one instead, should you wish, and just change the property calculation.

Answer (score 2):

My preferred approach would be to expose two public properties that update each other's backing fields. If your properties are read more frequently than they are updated, this would avoid repeatedly performing a multiplication or division operation on each read.

```
private double _bpm;
private double _bps;

private double Bpm
{
    get
    {
        return _bpm;
    }
    set
    {
        _bpm = value;
        _bps = value / 60;
    }
}

private double Bps
{
    get
    {
        return _bps;
    }
    set
    {
        _bps = value;
        _bpm = value * 60;
    }
}
```

Comment: That feels like micro-optimization at the cost of simplicity - and memory - until there's any *evidence* of it being a bottleneck. It's worth having up your sleeve in case the OP finds it *is* a bottleneck, but I usually take the simplest approach until I find that it doesn't perform as well as I need it to.

Answer (score 2):

Actually using properties are in `public` mode, so you can change your property to a value like below:

```
private double Bpm;

private double Bps
{
    get 
    {
        return Bpm / 60;
    }
}
```

With thanks to @Farhad Jabiyev.